# Openssl errors when building the bitcoin-core on macOS

Tags: bitcoin-core, mac, compiling, openssl, make

I have been trying to build bitcoin-core on macOS as I am reading the "Mastering Bitcoin" book from Andreas Antonopoulos.

I read the instructions for building the the bitcoin-core on macOS from the *doc/build-osx.md* file in the bitcoin repository and I installed all the libraries that are needed ( following the build-osx.md file ):

1. `brew install autoconf automake libtool boost miniupnpc openssl pkg-config protobuf qt` ( Also I installed a bunch of other libraries that I hoped would solve the issue, such as `sqlite python libevent qrencode`
2. The docs say "*You should see OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014.*" however now we have version 1.1.1k in 2021 as I am writing this. And also it asked me to do `brew link openssl --force` which I did.
3. I installed berkeley-db4, but I did with `brew install berkeley-db@4` since the link that is provided in the bitcoin docs doesn't work - `brew install https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Formula/berkeley-db4.rb -–without-java`
4. I have Xcode and its Command Line Tools
5. Then I did the `./autogen.sh` , `./configure` and `make`. The `./configure` went alright, without any errors, however when I type `make` I get the following errors.

```
/usr/local/include/boost/bind.hpp:36:1: warning: The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior. [-W#pragma-messages]
BOOST_PRAGMA_MESSAGE(
^
/usr/local/include/boost/config/pragma_message.hpp:24:34: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_PRAGMA_MESSAGE'
# define BOOST_PRAGMA_MESSAGE(x) _Pragma(BOOST_STRINGIZE(message(x)))
                                 ^
<scratch space>:85:2: note: expanded from here
 message("The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) " "in the global namespace is deprecated. Please use " "<boost/bind/bind.hpp> + using namespace boost::placeholders, " "or define BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior.")
 ^
In file included from bitcoind.cpp:9:
In file included from ./main.h:13:
./bignum.h:56:24: error: base class has incomplete type
class CBigNum : public BIGNUM
                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:80:16: note: forward declaration of 'bignum_st'
typedef struct bignum_st BIGNUM;
               ^
In file included from bitcoind.cpp:9:
In file included from ./main.h:13:
./bignum.h:61:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
        BN_init(this);
        ^
./bignum.h:66:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
        BN_init(this);
        ^
./bignum.h:67:14: error: no matching function for call to 'BN_copy'
        if (!BN_copy(this, &b))
             ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k/include/openssl/bn.h:219:9: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'CBigNum *' to 'BIGNUM *' (aka 'bignum_st *') for 1st argument
BIGNUM *BN_copy(BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *b);
        ^
In file included from bitcoind.cpp:9:
In file included from ./main.h:13:
./bignum.h:69:13: error: no matching function for call to 'BN_clear_free'
            BN_clear_free(this);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k/include/openssl/bn.h:218:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'CBigNum *' to 'BIGNUM *' (aka 'bignum_st *') for 1st argument
void BN_clear_free(BIGNUM *a);
     ^
In file included from bitcoind.cpp:9:
In file included from ./main.h:13:
./bignum.h:76:14: error: no matching function for call to 'BN_copy'
        if (!BN_copy(this, &b))
             ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k/include/openssl/bn.h:219:9: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'CBigNum *' to 'BIGNUM *' (aka 'bignum_st *') for 1st argument
BIGNUM *BN_copy(BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *b);
        ^
In file included from bitcoind.cpp:9:
In file included from ./main.h:13:
./bignum.h:83:9: error: no matching function for call to 'BN_clear_free'
        BN_clear_free(this);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1k/include/openssl/bn.h:218:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'CBigNum *' to 'BIGNUM *' (aka 'bignum_st *') for 1st argument
void BN_clear_free(BIGNUM *a);
     ^
In file included from bitcoind.cpp:9:
In file included from ./main.h:13:
./bignum.h:87:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(signed char n)        { BN_init(this); if (n >= 0) setulong(n); else setint64(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:88:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(short n)              { BN_init(this); if (n >= 0) setulong(n); else setint64(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:89:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(int n)                { BN_init(this); if (n >= 0) setulong(n); else setint64(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:90:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(long n)               { BN_init(this); if (n >= 0) setulong(n); else setint64(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:91:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(long long n)          { BN_init(this); setint64(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:92:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(unsigned char n)      { BN_init(this); setulong(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:93:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(unsigned short n)     { BN_init(this); setulong(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:94:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(unsigned int n)       { BN_init(this); setulong(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:95:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(unsigned long n)      { BN_init(this); setulong(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:96:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(unsigned long long n) { BN_init(this); setuint64(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:97:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    explicit CBigNum(uint256 n)   { BN_init(this); setuint256(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:101:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
        BN_init(this);
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
1 warning and 20 errors generated.
make[3]: *** [bitcoind.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I thought it was something with the openssl version so I have been trying to fix it by installing an older version but *brew* gave me errors everytime I tried something new. Now I have the latest version of openssl which is **1.1.1k**. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks

Comment: What version of Bitcoin Core are you trying to build? Openssl is no longer a dependency since 0.20

Comment: @AndrewChow I am trying to build v0.9.5rc1

Comment: I switched to v22.0rc2 and the problem seems to have been fixed. Thank you.